# Sending multiple HTML Tables in email

Tags: python

I have 3 HTML Tables from three .html files that I need to email using Python one below the other.

Currently only 1 table is getting attached. How to attach all 3?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time
import os,sys
from os import path
import re
import sys, ast
import subprocess
# Import smtplib for the actual sending function

from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
# Open a plain text file for reading.  For this example, assume that
# the text file contains only ASCII characters.

html = open('/root/madhu_test/bpstest/results/outnss.html')
htmla = open('/root/madhu_test/bpstest/results/outs2c.html')
htmlb = open('/root/madhu_test/bpstest/results/outrecommended.html')
html = html.read()
htmla = htmla.read()
htmlb = htmlb.read()

part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')
part3 = MIMEText(htmla, 'html')
part4 = MIMEText(htmlb, 'html')


msg.attach(part2)
msg.attach(part3) 
msg.attach(part4)


msg["From"] = "sauravb@juniper.net"
msg["To"] = "sauravb@juniper.net"
msg["Subject"] = "Sanity performance report"
p = Popen(["/usr/sbin/sendmail", "-t", "-oi"], stdin=PIPE)
p.communicate(msg.as_string())
```

Comment: You want to combine all those html files and send as a single email?

Comment: how is it coming out with the current code?

Comment: Yes.Currently only the first attachment is added.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same requirement. I used a single variable called "report" that contains all the html code in it. So I keep adding any number of tables to report varaible

```
report = ""
report += table1data
report += "<br><br>"
report += table2data
.
.
```

Finally attach this variable as the email text.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution might be to change `MIMEMultipart('alternative')` to `MIMEMultipart('mixed')`

This way it appends each attachment as opposed to choosing the best match for the email client.